# C libcurl verify if message is sent to webhook

Tags: c, libcurl

Because of variable `my_description` changes frequently I get this error:

> {"code": 50109, "message": "The request body contains invalid JSON."}

It is possible to modify the code below to verify if `libcurl` gets an error when sending the message to webhook? I want to print when the message is sent and when exist an error in sending a message.

I tried this:

```c
if(res != CURLE_OK)
    fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
```

but it is not helpful.
Anybody can help me, please? Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

#define nullptr ((void*)0)    

int main() {

char message[65500];

int max_len = sizeof message;

CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;

char webhook[] = "DISCORD_WEBHOOK";
char my_description[] = "Description";

snprintf(message, max_len,"{\"username\": \"Test\",\"embeds\":[{\"description\": \"%s\"}]}", my_description);

curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl) {
    struct curl_slist* headers = nullptr;
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/json");

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, webhook);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, message);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Anybody know? Please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried this:
>
> ```
> if(res != CURLE_OK)
>   fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
> ```

You might want to try this:

```
if(res != CURLE_OK) {
  fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
} else {
  long response_code = 0;
  curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &response_code);
  if(response_code != 200) {
    // Error
  }
}
```

An invalid JSON can be caused by quotes in `my_description`. Quotes must be replaced with escape sequences `\"`.

Comment: Actually is a problem, even if the message is sent successfully, it still appears as an error, I added this: 
if(response_code != 200) {
    printf("ERROR");
  }

Comment: I don't know the application protocol used in your server. Refer its documentation about possible successful codes if they are not exact 200. You might change the condition `200 <= response_code response_code <= 299`. Http codes 2xx are successful codes.

Comment: I modify value 200 into 204 and now it works

Comment: i printed response_code and it shows value of 204 for successfully sent message and 400 for fail

Comment: if(!(response_code >= 200 && response_code <= 299))  this is working great

Comment: You know how to hide the error {"code": 50109, "message": "The request body contains invalid JSON."} from output?

Comment: Set nothing doing except return [CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.html).

Comment: Ok, I hope I can handle it. thanks a lot!